# Does there exist an indistinguishability formal proof obfuscator?

Tags: software-obfuscation

A formal proof obfuscator is a mapping $\mathcal{O}$ such that whenever $P$ is a formal proof of a theorem $T$, then $\mathcal{O}(P)$ is a distribution of formal proofs of the same theorem $T$. An indistinguishability formal proof obfuscator is a formal proof obfuscator $\mathcal{O}$ such that whenever $P_{1},P_{2}$ are proofs of of a theorem $T$ the distributions $\mathcal{O}(P_{1}),\mathcal{O}(P_{2})$ are indistinguishable. Does there exist an indistinguishability formal proof obfuscator? Are there any references for an indistinguishability formal proof obfuscator or any formal proof obfuscator in general?

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not give $T$ as an input, the existence of such an $\mathcal{O}$ seems

like it should significant constraints on the is_a_proof_of relation:

For example, if there are proofs P<sub>0</sub>,P<sub>2</sub>,P<sub>1</sub> and Theorems T<sub>0</sub>,T<sub>1</sub>,T<sub>2</sub> such that

[for all elements i and j of {0,1,2}, ​ P<sub>i</sub> is_a_proof_of T<sub>j</sub> ​ if and only if ​ i ≠ j ]

then there would have to be a P such that P is a proof of *all three* of those theorems.

> For the rest of this answer, assume there is a function theor_of_ such that
>   
>   for all proofs P and theorems T, if P is a proof of T then ​ theor_of_(P) = T .

Under that assumption, sure. ​ ​ ​ For such a function theor_of_, one can

have $\mathcal{O}$ be given by ​ ​ ​ $\mathcal{O}(P)$ ​ = ​ [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) least proof of theor_of_(P) ​ .

That $\mathcal{O}$ is in P<sup>theor_of_[[1]](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#pnpk),NP</sup>.

You probably want $\mathcal{O}$ to be efficient, or at least significantly faster than brute force for suitable input lengths, even if NP is hard. ​ For that requirement, it becomes very significant that

you do not give the security parameter as input

and
you're not relating the lengths of the proofs

.
The distributions thus do not depend on the security parameter, so if they're indistinguishable then they're identical. ​ Efficiency in particular forces output-length to be not so much longer than input length, so for the resulting distributions to be identical, $\mathcal{O}$ must find a proof which is not so much longer than the *shortest* proof, regardless of how long its *input* proof is.

The latter is the much stricter requirement - For example, consider statements of the form "There exists an x such that $\big[\big[$x [satisfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) $\phi \big]$ or [length(x) = L]$\big]$", and proof systems for which the proofs of such statements are exactly ordered pairs of the statement and such an $x$.

By setting L so that it will be slightly greater than

$\big[\mathcal{O}$'s runtime on proofs of the resulting formula for which $x$ is a satisfying assignment$\big]$ (remember that L is only log(L) bits long) and giving $\mathcal{O}$ a proof with an L-bit $x$, $\mathcal{O}$ must solve $\phi$.

Even for proof systems that are not so insistent on constructiveness, one could try

replacing ​ length(x) = L ​ with something else such that $\big[$one also gets a proof but it's

probably hard to find a proof that's not sufficiently longer than assignments to $\phi \big]$.

Even if you [give the security parameter as an input] and [only require indistinguishability against [uniform](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34898/991) adversaries that must choose equal-length proofs], such an $\mathcal{O}$ for a

similarly-constructive proof system would suffice for inverting candidate one-way functions with probability greater than 1/3 ​ - ​ Just run it on proofs that give r for statements

"There exists an x such that f(x) is in {$\hspace{.02 in}$y,z}.", where a random one of

of y,z is the target image, the other of them is f(r), and r is chosen

uniformly from strings with length equal to the security parameter.

Thus, if one-way functions exist then for a feasible such $\mathcal{O}$ to exist,

the proof system must not be feasibly constructive.

Now, I'll finally give the positive results:

As warmup, if there is an efficient [non-interactive witness-indistinguishable proof system](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/599.pdf)

NIWIP for [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) with deterministic verifier, then for axiomatic systems S such that

a theor_of_ function, as described near the top of this answer, is efficiently computable

and
the proof system includes arithmetic and

[can prove enough about its own provability predicate]

and
there is a poly(k,M)-time algorithm for finding a proof in ​ S + [Con](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Truth_of_the_G.C3.B6del_sentence)(S) ​ that

NIWIP with security parameter k is sound for statements of length at most M

then there is an efficient $\mathcal{O}$ that takes as input

the security parameter, [in unary](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8174/991)

and
a length bound L, in unary

and
a proof in S of a [$\Pi_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy#The_arithmetical_hierarchy_of_formulas) formula

and outputs a proof in ​ S + [Con](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Truth_of_the_G.C3.B6del_sentence)(S) ​ of the same $\Pi_1$ formula,

such that the desired indistinguishability will hold when

the security parameters are equal

and
the length bounds are equal

and
the proofs both satisfy the length bound

.
Furthermore, if NIWIP's indistinguishability is perfect,

then $\mathcal{O}$ does not need the security parameter.

(In either case, use NIWIP on the existence of a proof of length at most L, prove the relevant

soundness property of NIWIP to deduce the existence of *a proof in S of* the $\Pi_1$ formula, and

then use Con(S) and [provable-in-S facts about being provable-in-S] to deduce the [$\Pi_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy#The_arithmetical_hierarchy_of_formulas) formula.)

It's finally time for the full result. ​ For axiomatic systems S<sub>0</sub> such that

a theor_of_ function, as described near the top of this answer, is efficiently computable

and
the proof system includes arithmetic and

[can prove enough about its own provability predicate]

, ​ ​ ​ with the axiomatic systems ​ S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>,S<sub>3</sub>,S<sub>4</sub>,...,S$_{\infty}$ ​ given by

S<sub>n+1</sub> is S<sub>n</sub> plus [the [schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema) with one axiom per [wff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) p, where those

axioms are padded (for example, by ANDing with 0=0) to each be longer

than n bits, and otherwise just assert "if p is provable in S<sub>n</sub> then p"]

and
S$_{\infty}$ ​ = ​ S<sub>0</sub> + S<sub>1</sub> + S<sub>2</sub> + S<sub>3</sub> + S<sub>4</sub> + ...

, if there is $\big[$an efficient [non-interactive witness-indistinguishable proof system](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/599.pdf) NIWIP for [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) with deterministic verifier$\big]$ and $\big[$a poly(k,M)-time algorithm for finding a proof in S$_{\infty}$

that NIWIP with security parameter k is sound for statements of length at most M$\big]$,

then then there is an efficient $\mathcal{O}$ that takes as input

the security parameter, [in unary](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8174/991)

and
a length bound L, in unary

and
a proof in S$_{\infty}$

and outputs a proof, also in S$_{\infty}$, of the same formula,

such that the desired indistinguishability will hold when

the security parameters are equal

and
the length bounds are equal

and
the proofs both satisfy the length bounds

.
As before, if NIWIP's indistinguishability is perfect,

then $\mathcal{O}$ does not need the security parameter.

(In either case, work as follows: ​ ​ ​ Proofs in S$_{\infty}$ of length at most L cannot use axioms that aren't in S<sub>L</sub>, so use NIWIP on the existence of a proof in S$_{\infty}$. ​ From there, prove the relevant soundness property of NIWIP to deduce the existence of *a proof in S<sub>L</sub> of* the relevant formula, and then use the relevant axiom from S<sub>L+1</sub> to deduce the relevant formula itself.)

I'm not aware of any candidates for that which [Shor's algorithm](http://koclab.cs.ucsb.edu/teaching/ecc/project/2015Projects/Green+Kizilkale.pdf) won't break.